# Blazor ApexCharts - Cannot show the repeated values on XAxis

Tags: c#, blazor, apexcharts

I am currently using ApexCharts to generate charts for analysis.

Is it possible to repeat items on the XAxis?

This is what I got:

[image: ApexCharts]

This is what I want:

[image]

View:

```
<ApexChart TItem="DataItem" Title="Measurement(mm)">
    <ApexPointSeries    TItem="DataItem"
                        Items="datas"
                        Name="Measurement"
                        SeriesType="SeriesType.Line"
                        XValue="@(e=>e.date)"
                        YValue="@(e=>e.value)" 

    />
</ApexChart>
```

Code:

```cs
public class DataItem
{
    public string date { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int value { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

List<DataItem> datas = new List<DataItem> 
{
    new DataItem { date = "2023-03-20 01:39:03", value = 3 },
    new DataItem { date = "2023-03-20 01:39:03", value = 4 },
    new DataItem { date = "2023-03-20 01:39:03", value = 3 },
    new DataItem { date = "2023-03-20 01:39:03", value = 5 },
    new DataItem { date = "2023-03-20 01:39:03", value = 5 },
    new DataItem { date = "2023-03-20 01:39:03", value = 6 },
    new DataItem { date = "2023-03-20 01:39:03", value = 7 },
    new DataItem { date = "2023-03-20 01:39:03", value = 9 },
    new DataItem { date = "2023-03-20 01:39:03", value = 13 }
};
```

I want the graph to show the repeated date instead of just the first item.

How can I set the configs? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe that this bug is similar to [Chart won't draw on Duplicate X-Axis value](https://github.com/apexcharts/Blazor-ApexCharts/issues/96) although the reported issue is for drawing a 2-line chart.

It is recommended to report this issue so that the repository owner understands the issue and fixes it.

A quick fix is applying the configuration: `XAxisType="XAxisType.Numeric"`.

```
<ApexChart TItem="DataItem" Title="Measurement(mm)" XAxisType="XAxisType.Numeric">
    <ApexPointSeries TItem="DataItem"
                     Items="datas"
                     Name="Measurement"
                     SeriesType="SeriesType.Line"
                     XValue="@(e=> e.date)"
                     YValue="@(e=>e.value)" />
</ApexChart>
```

> Demo

[image]